# Some users can't Contribute

Tags: user-accounts

All employees in my company are granted Contribute access through an Outlook group email list. I created a survey and also gave the employees instructions to set up Alerts for announcements. So far, two employees are unable to either Finish the survey or add an announcement. I have checked their individual rights and can't find anything that would deny them Contribute rights. Where else do I look?

Comment: Have you tried adding Contribute permissions manually to one of the users and check if the issue exists? Have you ensured the users have actually tried these procedures the right way (& in the right place)? Have you confirmed the users are using their "default" accounts with expected permissions? I'd start investigating this by excluding the possible mistakes by users.

Comment: are you using an AD group to give them access? if so the default Claims Security Token Service expires 10 hours from logging in.